# netbeans replace variable name when using auto complete instead of insert

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, ide, autosuggest

I have a problem when I want to change an existing variable with a new one using auto complete ctrl-space I write or navigate the new name but when selecting it, it gets insert where the cursor is instead of replacing the old variable. In Delphi IDE this was default behavior (i.e replace instead of insert at cursor position).

Example: if I want to replace **MyVar1** with MyVar2 and place the cursor right after *My* it becomes **MyVar2Var1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, when auto-complete box is shown, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, that had never occurred to me.

Comment: Is there a way to switch the behavior of _Enter_ and _Ctrl_ + _Enter_?